# Group comma separated elements in MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

It's kinda stupid question and I already made it work using php,but I was wondering can I group all the unique elements in a column separated by comma within my query call.

I have a column with comma separated tags

- `tag1`, `tag2`
- `tag2`, `tag3`
- `tag3`, `tag1`

currently I am making my query with `GROUP BY ('tag_col')` which returns as it is (like the list up there). In the end I have to output a loop with all the unique tags, which I've done within my php script.
The question had to begin that by using group by it groups as separate rows that contain for example:

- `tag1`, `tag2`

  and
- `tag2`, `tag1`

Ain't there smarter way to list them all as `tag1`,`tag2` etc. before sorting it with php.

Comment: This is why one uses a separate table to store tags

Comment: There are always 2 tags in tag_col ?

Comment: No, there are up to 20

Comment: Save yourself a world of pain. Normalise your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this i guess, it will allow you to concatenate all of them in one row by using `GROUP_CONCAT(tag_col)` and removing your group by.

Then with php you can turn it into an array and from there it's easy to remove any duplicates.